# do_shortcode autommatic content generation

Tags: shortcode, widgets

My parent theme has a do_shortcode function that automatically generates and displays content on the sidebar. i want to edit it and put some custom content there.. How to do it?

Comment: what is the shortcode inside `do_shortcode();` ? if it is `do_shortcode('[shortcode]');` then you should search `add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'function_name' );` in the functions.php or any other file linking to functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

you can remove shortcode output using below function

```
 remove_shortcode('shortcode_name')
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/

Answer (score 0):

`do_shortcode` outputs shortcode which is created using `add_shortcode`, so find out that shortcode function and check there are any action/filter hooks available.

Or

Use [`remove_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/) to remove the parent theme function and add your own code using [`add_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/). If the parent theme uses `function_exists` check while creating the shortcode then you don't need to worry about removing it. You can just override the function.